# how to write a program or a shell script to remove an existing xxx.framework(not imported from apple's libraries) from my project

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodeproj

*system:mac osx 10.11.2 , xcode 7.2*

i want to write a program or a shell script to **remove/add an existing xxx.framework(not imported from apple's libraries)** from my project.

i tried to use [XCodeEditor](https://github.com/appsquickly/XcodeEditor) like this:

```
XCProject *asProject = [[XCProject alloc] initWithFilePath:@"/Users/xxx/Desktop/project/test/testXCodeConfig/AAA.xcodeproj"];
XCTarget *aTarget = [asProject targetWithName:@"ccc"];
XCSourceFile *file = [asProject fileWithName:@"bbb.framework"];
NSLog(@"%d",originTarget.members.count);
[aTarget removeMemberWithKey:file.key];
NSLog(@"%d",aTarget.members.count);
[asProject save];
```

but it didnt work.i got the same count number printed twice.

anyone knows how to make it?
thanks!

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @Priyal Yes. As I remember, my code above works when the project contains only one target.